# How do you use bitwise-xor to win 3 pile nim?

Tags: scheme

I know how bitwise-xor works and I understand that the winning position is equal to 0. How do you determine which pile to adjust and how many to take away in order to create a winning position (given there are 3 piles)?

Comment: (make-move-instruction (bitwise-xor pile2) 2) The number of stones it removes is the (bitwise-xor pile2) the pile it removes it from is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xor the number of stones in each pile to get an xor-sum of the three piles. If the xor-sum is zero, there is no winning play. Otherwise, xor the xor-sum with the number of stones in each pile in turn, choose the first pile where the xor is less than the number of stones in the pile, and remove enough stones from the pile to make the xor zero, which makes the xor-sum of all three piles zero, which forces a win. See [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/08/nim/) for an implementation.